# Is there a man section or other doc repository for data structure definitions?

Tags: kernel, man, documentation

For the millionth time or so I had to look in `/usr/include/foo.h` to find the members of a `struct foo` or `foo_t` or whatever. There's a man section for library and kernel calls, some of which include descriptions of data structures and others not. Is there a single place to look up the definitions of kernel and library data structures?

Comment: Which data structure(s), specifically, are we talking about here?

Comment: Any of them. Think of all the struct whatever's in the C library that you sooner or later need to be non-opaque. Not to mention the various whatever_t's different functions need. Is there a way better than `grep -rl whatever /usr/include` to figure out where these are defined and what they are defined as?

Comment: No, though the manpages for your function typically either describe the struct or provide further information where the struct is defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU C library has a [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/) that includes documentation for all or most of the data structures in the standard library and extensions.  This has a [type index](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Type-Index.html#Type-Index).  Beware there's also a "GNU C Reference Manual", but it and the "GNU C *Library* Reference Manual" are two different things.

You can also autogenerate documentation sufficient for browsing data structures with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) (note that it works much better with stuff that's actually annotated for it, but it can be crudely used this way). I tried this here on `/usr/include` and it took < 2 minutes (producing, n.b., ~800 MB of html).  The steps were:

1. Create a basic config file somewhere (anywhere), `doxygen -g doxygen.conf`.
2. Edit the file and change the following settings:

   ```
   OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = /home/foo/whatever # documentation goes here
   OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
   EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
   INPUT                  = /usr/include
   FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h
   RECURSIVE              = YES
   GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
   ```

   Note that all those already exist in the config file, you need to search through and change/set the values as shown.
3. Generate: `doxygen doxygen.conf`.

Now open `/home/foo/whatever/html/files.html`.  There is an `index.html`, but it is probably WTF'd up (again, doxygen is primarily intended for stuff that's purposefully annotated for it), so the file list is of the most predicatable entry point.  There's also a copious "Data Structure Index", but for whatever reason, not everything you would think is indexed in it.  E.g., there's a `structstat.html` you can reach by following the file list, *asm-generic -> stat.h*, but "struct stat" is not mentioned in the "Data Structures Index".   Many standard C lib things follow this pattern: there's a macro/define/typedef in the predicatable header (`sys/stat.h`) that pulls in something extern that ends up being in a platform/system specific header in, e.g. `asm-generic.h`.  I'm sure you've noticed this before.  The stat example is not so bad in so far as at least the final definition is still called `struct stat` and not `struct _fooX_stat`.

So this takes some getting used to and is, in the end, not much better than tooling around with `grep`.  It also has the dis(?)advantage that non-user fields are included (e.g., compare the `struct stat` as documented above to its description in `man 2 stat`).  For the standard library (and GNU extensions) the reference manual is much better.  However, WRT stuff that's not in that manual, it is slightly better than nothing.  I'd recommend that if you do want to use it that way, it would be better to do individual directories independently rather than the whole shebang (clue: you can set `RECURSION = NO`).  800 MB of html is pretty unwieldy.

Comment: As I feared. Autogenerated documentation has always been disappointing to me, personally, but it's probably marginally better than grep. Thanks!